# ¿Por qué SoapClient() me funciona con PHP5 y no con php7?

Tags: php

Tengo un sistema que controla las huellas dactilares de varios relojes para la asistencia de los trabajadores, una de sus funciones es extraer esas huellas del sdk de los relojes para un base de datos **postgreSQL** mediante una tarea programada en el servidor con un `crontab` llamando a **task_marcas_reloj.php** que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, esto siempre funciono en **php 5** pero al migrar el sevidor a **php 7** ya no funciona. Mi archivo **task_marcas_reloj.php**:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
require "tasker.php";
$task = new Tasker();
$task->marcas_usuarios();
?>
```

La clase **Tasker()**

```
Class Tasker
{
    protected $client;


    /**
     * Task constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
             //La direccion wsdl funciona correctamente, lo verifique al abrirlo en el navegador
            $wsdl = 'http://localhost/wsdl/relojdirecto';

            $options = array(
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                'exceptions' => 0
            );
            $this->client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            print_r($e);
        }
    }
   function marcas_usuarios()
    {
        $this->client->marcas_usuarios_directo();
        return;
    }
}
```

La clase **Service_Relojdirecto**

```
class Service_Relojdirecto extends Soap_Service
{

    protected $relojModel;
    protected $pagoModel;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->relojModel = Model::factory('relojdirecto');
        $this->pagoModel = Model::factory('operaciones');
    }
    public function marcas_usuarios_directo()
    {
        $data = $this->relojModel->marcas_usuarios_directo();
       //El metodo updateService() se encarga de hacer todo el tratamiento de los datos a guardar en la base de datos
        if ($this->pagoModel->updateService($data)) {
            $this->relojModel->clear_logs();
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

Este es el error que me muestra al ejecutar la tarea antes mencionada.

> PHP Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL operation failed with code
>   1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
>   /home/administrator/sitios_disponibles/RelojProy/modules/asistencia/task/tasker.php
>   on line 29 PHP Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient(): Failed to enable
>   crypto in
>   /home/administrator/sitios_disponibles/RelojProy/modules/asistencia/task/tasker.php
>   on line 29 PHP Warning: 
>   SoapClient::SoapClient(http://localhost/wsdl/relojdirecto):
>   failed to open stream: operation failed in
>   /home/administrator/sitios_disponibles/RelojProy/modules/asistencia/task/tasker.php
>   on line 29 PHP Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning :
>   failed to load external entity
>   "http://localhost/wsdl/relojdirecto"
>   in
>   /home/administrator/sitios_disponibles/RelojProy/modules/asistencia/task/tasker.php
>   on line 29 PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load
>   from
>   'http://localhost/wsdl/relojdirecto'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "http://localhost/wsdl/relojdirecto"

Answer (score 1):

Saludos te sugiero realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
$url     = "http://localhost/wsdl/relojdirecto";
$context = stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
));

$service = new SoapClient($url, array('stream_context' => $context));
```

Para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la documentación:

[stream_context_create](https://php.net/stream_context_create)

[HTTP context options](https://php.net/context.http)

[SSL context options](https://php.net/context.ssl)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Me funciona parcialmente, no me muestra el error antes mencionado pero nunca me entra a la clase **Service_Relojdirecto** entra al metodo `function marcas_usuarios()
    {
        $this->client->marcas_usuarios_directo();
        return;
    }` en la llamada de `$this->client->marcas_usuarios_directo()`